# Move the whole word in contenteditable div to next line in case there is no place

Tags: css, contenteditable, word-break

I have a contenteditable div. when I am typing inside, in case I am typing a word in the end of the line and there is no place to the whole word, it move to the next line, but when I open it filled, the word is break in the middle and a part of it move to next line.
I want it in any case to move the whole word to the next line.

[when I am typing the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sruTu.png)
[when I open it filled:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSLpc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the below in your css.

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3obyr7k2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `word-break: normal;` to the paragraph tag.

Hope it helps!